# Location header php

Tags: php

Вообщем такая проблема, что надо при входе системы чтобы header(navigation.php) менялся на (login-navigation)

[image: Находятся они в одной папке]

Перенаправление header я делаю в файле login-navigation.php

```
<?php session_start();
  include_once 'db.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
 header("Location: login-user.php");
}
?>
```

Изначально у меня страница поделена на header, content, footer.

Header на странице index я вызываю данным образом:

```
    <header class="header">
  <div>
    <?php include('navigation.php');
    ?>
  </header>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что остается тот же header

Comment: А с какого ради ему меняться, если вы его статично записали, без какой либо динамики? Где логика?

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто перепутали (бывает у новичков): функция header() в PHP — это http-запрос, а у вас header — это файл/тэг/блок и т.п. Вместо функции header() в своём коде подключайте файл с помощью include() или require() с нужным файлом.

Comment: Спасибо :). Не легко быть новичком